# How can I solve this spherical trigonometry problem?

Tags: trigonometry

Determine the distance between Manila (Latitude: 14.604◦N, Longitude: 120.982◦ E) and Phnom Penh, Cambodia (Latitude: 11.562◦N, Longitude: 104.916◦ E). If at what time will I arrived in Phnom Penh, Cambodia if the airplane leaves Manila at 9:25pm with an average speed of 400 Knots?

```
coor1 = {14.604, 120.982};
coor2 = {11.562, 104.916};
```

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: In V10.3, this might work `TravelDistance[CityData[{"Manila", "Manila", "Philippines"}], CityData[{"Phnom Penh", "Cambodia"}]] / Quantity[400, "Knots"]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
coor1 = {14.604, 120.982};
coor2 = {11.562, 104.916};

UnitConvert[GeoDistance[coor1, coor2], "Km"]
```

> ```
> Quantity[1774.02, "Kilometers"]
> ```

```
GeoGraphics[
 {
  PointSize[Large]
  , Point[GeoPosition@{coor1, coor2}]
  , Red,
  Line[GeoPosition@{coor1, coor2}]
  }
 , GeoRange -> Quantity[2000, "Km"]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
UnitConvert[
 GeoDistance[coor1, coor2]/Quantity[400, "Knots"]
 , "SI"]
```

> ```
> Quantity[8621.04, "Seconds"]
> ```

```
 DatePlus[TimeObject[{9, 25, 0}], Quantity[8621.035527369528`, "Seconds"]]
```

> ```
> TimeObject[{11, 48, 41.0355}, TimeZone -> 1.]
> ```

Comment: It might be noteworthy that these distances are not plain "spherical" distances, but measured over the reference ellipsoid. In case of geography, this is of course what people probably want...

Comment: So time of arrival would be 11:48:41 am? and yes kirma I'm aware that this are not spherical distances :) but they are close ones. Thank you so much rhermans!

Comment: But not local time!